# I have a micro sd card that can be read and written in windows, but it can't be written in VMware. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Tags: vmware

I have a 16GB micro SD card that is going through a Lexar microSD RDR (0815) adapter. I can read and write to it on windows, but in VMware I can only edit existing files. I can't delete any files and I can't drag and drop, or create new files to it.

I ran the dmesg | tail command and this was the output:

```
dmesg | tail
[ 6961.995715] scsi host9: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 6962.999542] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Lexar    microSD RDR      0815 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 6963.000610] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 6963.304586] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] 31116288 512-byte logical blocks: (15.9 GB/14.8 GiB)
[ 6963.312507] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 6963.312515] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 6963.320559] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 6963.356589]  sdc: sdc1
[ 6963.380491] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 6967.888789] FAT-fs (sdc1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

I ran fsck and this was the result.

```
fsck.ext4: Permission denied while trying to open /dev/sda1
You must have r/w access to the filesystem or be root
swgroup@fwdev2-smount:~/Desktop$ 
swgroup@fwdev2-smount:~/Desktop$ sudo fsck
[sudo] password for swgroup: 
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

What should I do?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, `unmount` the drive. Low-level disk utilities (like `fsck`) change the physical disk, which may no longer match the kernel data stored by `mount`. Then, since you want low-level access to the drive, you must run as `root`, using `sudo`:

```
 sudo umount /dev/sda1
 sudo fsck.vfat -a /dev/sda1
```

The `-a` option to `fsck.vfat` asks for automatic repair. See `man fsck.vfat` for other choices.